# Assign textbox's value to another texbox without a botton

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I want to know what is the best way to assign a value to textbox 2 instantly as the user write this value in textbox 1 ie. Directly showing what the user is entering in textbox1 also in textbox2 at the same. I'm using MVC5 aspx pages..
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to use jquery or javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a onkeyup event listener to your first element(Whenever a key is pressed, the value in first textbox is also entered in second.). Then call the function like

`function enterAmt(ev) {
    document.getElementById('amt2').value = ev.value;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use javascript or jquery for it, suppose you have two textboxes.

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox1"/>
<input type="text" id="txtBox2"/>
```

You have to write keyup event for the textbox and copy its value in second.

### JQUERY:

```
$("#txtBox1").on('keyup', function () {
    $("#txtBox2").val($(this).val())
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the solution to the absolutely same question: [Textbox onchange in ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1268110.aspx?Textbox%20onchange%20event%20)